# Change the value of many input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, input

First Stack Overflow question here. I've read over a dozen questions on similar issues, but none of them quite match the problem that I'm struggling with. My Web App is a "Teacher Gradebook" to keep track of scores for various assignments. The view shows a large table listing students, and their scores. When the user clicks a "Class period" button, the table should change to show the students and scores for the new class period. Using the following code, the input fields will not update:

```
$scope.changeClassPeriod = function(classPerIndex) {
    $scope.currClassPer = classPerIndex;
    var thisClassPeriod = $scope.classPeriods[$scope.currClassPer];
    for (var i = 0; i < thisClassPeriod.assignments.length; i++) {
        $("#head"+i).text(thisClassPeriod.assignments[i].assignmentName);
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < thisClassPeriod.students.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < thisClassPeriod.assignments.length; j++) {
            $($('#scoresheet')[0].rows[i+1].cells[j+2]).val(thisClassPeriod.students[i].scores[j]);
        };
    };
};
```

The strange thing is, when I use the "Text" command instead of the "Val" command, the view updates so that all tds show the scores that I expect. The downside is, this approach changes all of the input fields into text fields, so the user can no longer edit them.

```
   $($('#scoresheet')[0].rows[i+1].cells[j+2]).text(thisClassPeriod.students[i].scores[j]);
```

In a similar question posted elsewhere on Stack Overflow, some other helpers mentioned that unique id is needed for each input field. Is that a problem specific to input fields, but not to text fields?

Comment: Unique ID's are always needed, for all elements on a page, you can't have duplicate ID's, jQuery will only fetch the first element with any given ID. The second code snippet can't possibly work, as it's a syntax error.

Comment: Edited to fix the syntax error. Needed to close the parentheses around '#scoresheet'. The 'text' can also be changed back to 'val' with Void's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `.text()` is working and `.val()` is not working then you are targeting some other element then a input field. Try doing this:

```
$($('#scoresheet')[0].rows[i+1].cells[j+2]).find('input').val(thisClassPeriod.students[i].scores[j]);
```

If your rest of the code is fine then this should do the job.

Comment: Yes! This did the job nicely. Thank you.